# Something very strange with WPF solution

Tags: wpf, vb.net

This is happening in several old or new projects in my WPF based solution. I have just added a window called `Dashboard`, and in the generated 'Dashboard.xaml.vb`file, I entered the following code. Note it normally pastes`InitializeComponent`in for you when you create`Sub New`, but now it doesn't. So, I have:

```
Public Class DashBoard

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Ans the compiler complains that:

> Error 15  'InitializeComponent' is not declared. It may be inaccessible
>   due to its protection level.

It's as if the IDE doesn't know this is the code behind for a Window. Some kind of partial class or link is missing, yet in the vbproj file, we do still find the link:

```
<Compile Include="Bridge.xaml.vb">
  <DependentUpon>Bridge.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

I am using PostSharp on all projects for automatic error logging, but it has never given me trouble before. It is remarkably well behaved.

***ADDED:***

`Dashboard.xaml' looks like:

```
<Window x:Class="DashBoard"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="DashBoard" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and `Dashboard.xaml.vb' looks like this:

```
Public Class DashBoard

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

To relate you `Dashboard.xaml.vb` file with the existing `Dashboard.xaml` file, you need to:

1. declare the class `partial`, and
2. make it inherit from the WPF `window` base class, for example:

`Public Partial Class Dashboard Inherits Window`

As long as your class does not inherit from `Window`, it's clear that it doesn't find the `InitializeComponent` method.

However, this does not explain why the necessary code parts are not generated automatically. How does the `Dashboard.xaml` file look like?

Comment: That doesn't do it, I've tried. VS is supposed to do all of that in Black Box magic for a VB.NET project. Thinking of telling the client to stuff it if Ii can't use C#.

Comment: Check if the `.xaml` and `.xaml.vb` files are connected to each other by closing VS and opening the `.vbproj` file in some text editor, then search for `Dashboard.xaml.vb`: It should contain an entry similar to `<Compile Include="Dashboard.xaml.cs"><DependentUpon>Dashboard.xaml</DependentUpon></Compile>`, since this tells VS that these two files "belong together"

Comment: they are connected like that.

Comment: @ProfK You don't show that in your question. The question shows Bridge.xaml not Dashboard.xaml.